# Sitecore PAAS Installation failure

Tags: paas

We are trying to install Sitecore 9.0.2 XP rev. 180604 on Azure and we are getting error: `ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE`.

Any inputs would be helpful.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 12:31:16 PM - Resource 

Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions 'XXXsitecoredev-cm/MSDeploy' 

failed with message '{
  "status": "failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "Failed",
        "**message": "Package deployment failed\r\nAppGallery Deploy Failed: 
'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedClientServerException: An error occurred during execution of the database 
script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: \"1\" and \"43\". The verbose log might have more 
information about the error. The command started with the following:\r\n\"declare @ApplicationName nvarchar(256) = 
'sitecore\"\r\n Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server 
is not responding. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE. ---&gt; System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not 
responding**. ---&gt; System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out\r\n   --- End of inner exception 
stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, 
Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject 
stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior 
runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject 
stateObj, Boolean&amp; dataReady)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, 
Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)\r\n   at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean 
sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean&amp; usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)\r\n   at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DBStatementInfo.Execute(DbConnection 
connection, DbTransaction transaction, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Int32 timeout)\r\n   --- End of inner exception 
stack trace ---\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DBStatementInfo.Execute(DbConnection connection, DbTransaction 
transaction, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Int32 timeout)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DBConnectionWrapper.ExecuteSql(DBStatementInfo sqlStatement, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, 
Int32 timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlScriptToDBProvider.AddHelper(DeploymentObject source, Boolean 
whatIf)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.AddChild(DeploymentObject source, Int32 position, 
DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAddChild(DeploymentObject 
destParent, DeploymentObject sourceObject, Int32 position)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject 
sourceObject)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, 
DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, 
String syncSessionId)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, 
DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.Deploy(String deploymentSite, String siteSlotId, Boolean doNotDelete)\r\n 
  at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__17.MoveNext()'"
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

Comment: do you use sitecore marketplace module?

Comment: No its using ARM Templates

Comment: So I have seen this timeout before. Not often, but on some of my repeated attempts at installing PaaS I would get a timeout where Azure didn't quite make available the infrastructure resources before the application deploymwnt tried to use it. In those cases I would delete the Resource Group and redeploy. Maybe try that.